# How to read data from an XML file and store it into database (MySQL)?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, xml

I need to get data from an XML file and store it into a MySQL Database. I am thinking of using a SAX Parser for parsing the data but I am not sure of how to store data efficiently into database, I am thinking of few technologies like [JDBC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) and [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29) but I wanted to ask about what would be the efficient way of doing it?

Note: Here programming language is Java.

Comment: That's pretty broad - you're going to need to elaborate a bit on your actual data and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I am getting online catalog as data along with some business rules and I need to modify the incoming data depending on some business rules and other considerations and create a canonical data model and than store relevant data into MySQL Database.

Comment: Questions here is to accomplish following task what is better tool, Task: "Need to parse an XML File,which has data as well as decision rules, and store data into database(mysql right now but can change in future) and talk to java code which deals with ILOG JRules for Decision Rules present in XML File", now discussion is about which is better tool to accomplish the task, PERL or Java, and consideration is of speed of execution as compared to development speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Castor](http://www.castor.org) witch is an open source data binding framework for moving data from 
  XML to Java programming language objects and from Java to 
  databases.

I found also article series in [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/xml/libraryview.jsp?search_by=Data+binding+with+Castor) that describe using Castor suited to your needs.

Comment: @Cetnar: Thank you very much for the information. I will go through it.

Comment: @Cetnar: Does it scale up well for large set of Data (>1GB)

Comment: @Rachel: Do you have large (>1GB) xml files? If performance is an issue you can try others JAX libriaries like http://www.jibx.org/ or parse xml with StAX parser. Here id link to performance tests of similar libraries http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library /x-databdopt2/ - bittly outdates I suppouse

Comment: @Cetnar: My xml file is larger than 1GB and yes performance is the major issue also if am using castor than I can do mapping of java objects in to MySQL using it but if am planning to use jibx or StAX than what would be best approach to map java objects into MySQL ? Hibernate/JPA/JDBC or which technology will be efficient for my concern ?

Comment: If you plan only move (and modify on the fly) data from xml do database in my opinion plain JDBC will be most efective from perfomance view.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using JAXB for reading in the XML to Java objects and JPA for writing them into the database. You can create a single data model using Java classes that have both annotations for XML binding using JAXB and database persistence annotations using JPA.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Foo")
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {
    // ...
}
```

Information on [JAXB annotations](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html).
Information on [JPA](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/index.html?javax/persistence/EntityManager.html).

Comment: I am new to both JAXB and JPA, where would you recommend me to go and get relevant information useful for my task.

Comment: EclipseLink is a good place to look as it provides both JAXB & JPA (it's the RI) implementations.  An example of how to use these technologies can be found here - http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JPA

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many factors. If your XML is too large ( > 1GB or comparable with your total memory), then you should use SAX and I don't think there would be other solutions. If it's small (say smaller than 100MB), simply load the whole XML into a Document object using JAXP:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder parser = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = parser.parse(source);
```

You probably have elements or attributes mappied to columns on DB. You can then query elements/attrs using XPath for simplicity and write them to DB. It this is a one-time conversion, I recommend using simple JDBC. Don't think for JPA or Hibernate, as it just increases your development time for a routine data conversion scenario.

Comment: @Mohsen: It is not one time conversion meaning one it is stored in MySQL than I will in future might have to change it depending upon business/decision rules changes, so still with my requirement JDBC would be right option to go for or use Hibernate or JPA or some other ORM technology like TopLink, Ibatis would be useful ?

Answer (score 0):

You may store XML into mySQL directly using blob... if you want efficient indexing and high performance, VTD-XML has built-in ability to index/query/update XML document, making it a better alternative than SAX and DOM, here is a link to a related article

[Index XML documents with VTD-XML](http://soa.sys-con.com/node/453082)

Comment: I have to do some kind of operations on XML depending upon decision rules and so will this approach be useful in my concern ?