# Should I use Perl or PHP for parsing a large XML file?

Tags: php, xml, perl

I want to parse a large XML file and I have two options: Perl or PHP. Being new to both languages what would be your suggestion about language of choice for parsing a large XML file?

And what modules are more appropriate for the task at hand?

Comment: What happened to "> 15 GB"? Convinced your boss that that was a bad idea?

Comment: According to latest specification, it was mentioned that it would be around mentioned size. Thank you Manni for guiding and providing accurate advice. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Good for you. Must be nice to have that one off your chest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the language that you are most comfortable with.

If you decide to use Perl, please refer back to the "parsing XML using Perl"-questions you asked recently:

- [What is the best tool for parsing XML and storing data in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561045/what-is-the-best-tool-for-parsing-xml-and-storing-data-in-a-database-closed)
- [How to read data from an XML file and store it into database(MySQL) ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1544676/how-to-read-data-from-an-xml-file-and-store-it-into-databasemysql)
- [What is the best way to validate XML against XML Schema, parsing it and storing data back to MySQL Database using Perl ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578281/what-is-the-best-way-to-validate-xml-against-xml-schema-parsing-it-and-storing-d)
- [What would be your choice of XML Parsers in Perl for parsing > 15 GB Files ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590504/what-would-be-your-choice-of-xml-parsers-in-perl-for-parsing-15-gb-files)

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Both languages have highly-developed XML parsing utilities, so which is "best" depends on other factors.

Answer (score 4):

XML is usually parsed in one of two modes: stream or DOM. DOM is convenient, but unsuitable for large files. [XML::Twig from CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig) has mixed mode, which has advantages of both modes.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a built in function called [simplexml](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) which makes it very easy to handle XML files.

Comment: Patrick, ever loaded 1Gig file into DOM in an interpreted language? I did. NOT pretty.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the cuff - I have no knowledge of the specific XML parsing capabilities of either language - I would say if it's parsing, go Perl.  Perl's regular expression support is excellent and makes it the language of choice when there is parsing to be done.  Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Regular expressions have little to do with parsing non-regular languages.

Comment: Are you suggesting to parse XML with regular expressions?